# The output of ADC (AD7091R-5) is slowly rising with constant input

Tags: pcb, adc

I have a circuit board with an [AD7091R-5](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad7091r-5.pdf) analog to digital converter. I'm reading the output via I2C using a particle board (much like an Arduino.)

I'm reading the register for channel 0 and 1 as I intend, but there's a constant rise in the output of the ADC on both channels. I've connected to a mA tester that delivers 20mA to one channel and I've tried with different power supplies. The other channel is connected to a temperature sensor.

What can cause a slow rise in the output with constant input?

There are a few other components on the circuit board I'm not entirely sure about but I can figure it out if it's relevant.

Edit*
(a)

[image: Schematic of the 3.3V powersupply]

[image: Schematic of the ADC]

[image: Schematic of the analog 16V powersupply]

The other components is the particleboard, some for digital input and output and for battery control. I haven't included those are they relevant?

(b)
Regarding the setup. 
 I've connected at temperature transmitter to the first analog input and the mA tester to the second (there's only the two).
 I wanted to scale the the output of the ADC's in the particle board when it kept being too low so i noticed that the value was rising. I used the mA tester to test the values for a 4-20 mA input. At first connected in 'closed loop' and secondly with external 24VCD.

I'm currently trying to only have one active channel on the I2C as Spehro Pefhany suggested.

Comment: 20 mA into the input of an ADC might easily be enough to destroy it or cause it to malfunction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is bad timing so that you get some of the temperature reading smeared into the other input. To test for that, change the firmware to measure only one channel.

Another possibility is that the reference is changing (voltage decreasing with time). You can measure the reference voltage directly to check that out.

If you failed to use the recommended 2.2uF capacitor on Refin/Refout that could certainly cause reference instability and changes in the readings. Check Regcap as well.

Comment: Okay thanks alot! I will check those things out. I will get back then.

Comment: I've tried to change so that only one channel is active but the outputvalue is still slowly rising. 
I'm pretty sure that the 2.2uF on Refin/Refout is in place - I've added some schematics. I'll see if i can measure the refrence somehow.

Comment: I don't see much obviously wrong from the schematic. Suggest you measure the voltage across the 120Ω resistor as well in case it's got a temperature coefficent that's causing the issue. Also, the 51R+4.7nF is a bit heavy loading for a CMOS op-amp, it will negatively affect the phase margin. I don't think this is a problem but 1nF across the 1KΩ feedback resistors would improve the phase margin.

Comment: I measured the reference voltage you pointed out, Spehro Pefhany. When I measure it, it drops quickly to about 0.6V, and the output rises accordingly.
Any ideas to why that is or how i can fix it?

Comment: Well, that's not subtle at all. There are only a few parts connected to that net. Inspect thoroughly for open solder joints, or short,s then replace the cap, ADC and op-amp maybe in that order.

Comment: I apparently failed to set the configuration to the internal power supply. It seems to be working now. Thanks a lot for the help and guidance. :)